# How can I force an error in code without stoping the execution in quarto?

Tags: quarto

I'm creating a document for students using quarto.
One of the things I want to teach is how to read and understand error messages, so I was planning in creating wrong code blocks to force certain error messages (like the one below):

```py
a_list = [1,2,"a"]
a_list[3]
# I want to generate an error to explain that python starts counting at 0
```

Regretfully, when I write the code above, quarto complains (with good reason) and will stop executing the rest of the code blocks and rendering the file.

Is there a way to get the error message while not stoping the execution?

I thought something like this would work, but it doesnt:

```
# | error: true
a_list[3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me:

````
---
title: test-error
---    

```{python}
#| error: true
a_list = [1,2,"a"]
a_list[3]
```
````

It produces the following output:

[image: The output generated by the snippet above, including "Index Error: list index out of range"]

One thing to make sure is that the `#| error: true` line is at the beginning of the cell, and that there's no spaces between `#` and `|`.

You can also enable this behaviour across the whole document in the yaml header, like so:

````
---
title: test-error
execute:
  error: true
---    

```{python}
a_list = [1,2,"a"]
a_list[3]
```

```{r}
stop("Another error that could stop my .qmd from evaluating")
```
````

Comment: Thank you! I had a space between # and | ! I couldn't see it until I pasted your code from here and I had to use git, to see the change! Thanks for being my rubber duck, fellow Carlos.

Comment: This is certainly confusing behavior on our part. In the case of Python, some code formatters don't like `#|`.  We're actually going to change this to support spaces in the future, but we don't right now.